# Why does my left alt key trigger escape in linux?

Tags: linux, xorg, xkb

For some reason, my left Alt key triggers escape. I've confirmed this using `xev`:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0xf6, subw 0x0, time 299729, (1524,198), root:(1526,318),
    state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 9
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
mbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0xf6, subw 0x0, time 299875, (1524,198), root:(1526,318),
    state 0x18, keycode 64 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 9
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False
```

They keycode detected is 64, which according to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` is `LALT`. However, the keysym shows as `Escape`. Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this? I'm running Arch Linux.

*Edit:* The output of `setxkbmap -print` is:

```
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+us:2+inet(evdev)"        };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
};
```

Comment: Look at `xmodmap -pke | grep 64`. If it's assigned to `Escape`, you can fix it with `xmodmap -e ...`, but of course the question is how it ended up there. Please also edit question with output of `setxkbmap -print`.

Comment: I've added the output of `xkbmap -print`.  Still not sure what's causing it to be mapped to Escape.

Comment: that extra `+us:2` in the symbols is a little weird (means you have a second `us` layout active) but shouldn't be the cause of the esc-on-lalt issue.  did you check @dirkt's `xmodmap` test?  do you have an old `.Xmodmap` file lying around in your home directory?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually gave in and started with a fresh .config dir, and that resolved it. The issue might have been related to Gnome, but I'm not sure.